# Missing resource: in SOATest Jenkins configuration

Tags: jenkins, soa

I am setting up Jenkins for parasoft SOATest and setting the shell commands for execution  of .tst. But when I try to build job through jenkins it throws following error:

**ERROR: Missing Resources: The following symbols/resources were specified but were not found in the workspace. Ensure thy are valid and are related to the workspace.**
**location/xxx.tst**
Although I have specified correct path for the resource it throws this error.

Can someone please guide me on the same. 
Also please let me know if there are any documents/links to refer for the same.

Comment: Copy the console.log with the error and verify your workspace directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check in Parasoft's SOAtest documentation option **-import** ( the import process based on eclipse project definition so be sure that you have also .project file)

You should first import tst into workspace as first step in Jenkins' job, the second step should execution of particular test with SOAtest **-config** option.

You can find examples and explanation of all options in SOAtest's user manual.
and check also following url http://build.parasoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I encountered and resolved the same problem. Make sure the .tst has proper permission. It needs to be executable.

```
chmod 777 xxx.tst
```